# Angular не следит за масивом

Tags: javascript, angular

Здравствйете, возникла такая проблема, есть код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  ng-app="phonecatApp">
    <head>
        <title>GredTech</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css//style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">


        <script type="text/javascript">




            var journal = [];




            function addEntry2(name,pay,test) {

                journal.push({

                    name: name,
                    pay: pay,
                    test: test  

                });

            }

                addEntry2("001",150,1);     
                addEntry2("002",150,2);
                addEntry2("003",150,3);
                addEntry2("004",100,4);
                addEntry2("005",100,5);








            var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

            phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope){

                $scope.phones = journal;

            });


            $(document).ready( function () {

                $("#add").bind("click", may1); 

            });

            function may1 () {

                var a = $('#addF').val();

                addEntry2(a,a,a);

                console.log(journal);

            };




        </script>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">


        <div id="spisok">

            <ul ng-repeat="phone in phones">

                <li>{{phone.name}}</li>


            </ul>

        </div>

        <input id="addF" type="text"/>
        <button id="add">+</div>

    </body> 
</html>
```

При клике на кнопку я беру значения инпута и помещаю обэкт в масив journal , но автоматического обновления в списку

не происходит, хотя через консоль вывожу масив и он увеличивается, в чем пробела?

Comment: Проблема в том, что Вы изменяете массив в обход ангуляра, и ангуляр не знает, что он изменился. Вообще, смешивать jQuery и ангуляр - это обычно не очень хорошая практика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не Знаю зачем вы так все усложняете

```js
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.phones = [];
  $scope.addToList = function() {
    this.phones.push({
      name: this.name
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl" ng-app="phonecatApp">
  <div id="spisok">
    <ul ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <li>{{phone.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input ng-model="name" type="text"/>
  <button ng-click="addToList()">+</button>
</body>
```

Comment: "Не Знаю зачем вы так все усложняете" нехватает знаний((..вам ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо!!!

Comment: @James, Если понравился ответ, то почему бы не отметить его зеленой галочкой?))